# A build function returned null,The offending widget is: BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState> in flutter_bloc package

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am a beginner in flutter as well as in flutter_bloc where i'm trying to get the widget in blocbuilder but getting the "A build function returned null. The offending widget is:BlocBuilder. Build functions must never return null." Below is the bloc code and also the null error which is from console.

```
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: BlocListener<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                },
                child: BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is NotificationLoadedState) {
                      return NotificationIconBuild();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
  Widget NotificationIconBuild() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),])}
```

> Error from console log

```
I/flutter (13632): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13632): The following assertion was thrown building BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>(dirty,
I/flutter (13632): state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>#7fa62):
I/flutter (13632): A build function returned null.
I/flutter (13632): The offending widget is:
I/flutter (13632):   BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>
I/flutter (13632): Build functions must never return null.
I/flutter (13632): To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return
I/flutter (13632): "Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return
I/flutter (13632): "Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".
I/flutter (13632): 
I/flutter (13632): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (13632):   BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>
I/flutter (13632):   file:///C:/Users/Nabil/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_save/lib/home_page.dart:77:24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you only specify one `if` condition for your state which is `NotificationLoadedState`. Your Bloc must have tried to build other state which is not specified therefore resulting `BlocBuilder` returning null.

For quick fix, you can just change your `BlocBuilder` to something like this for now.

```
                child: BlocBuilder<NotificationBloc, NotificationState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is NotificationLoadedState) {
                      return NotificationIconBuild();
                    } else {
                      return Container();,
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because BlocBuilder requires return. But you defined only a return when ***condition*** is true. But when the condition is false, it will return null. That is why it gives this error. So you must add ***else*** block or ***return*** statement.

And in new version of bloc, if you want to use BlocBuilder and BlocListener together, you can use ***BlocConsumer*** widget.

**You can check it:** [BlocConsumer Example](https://github.com/KenanYusubov/Handy/blob/master/lib/presentation_layer/pages/register_page.dart)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is really silly is that I used `BlocListener` instead of `BlocBuilder`, and it throws the above error, hope it can help someone.